# Can I create a movie from imported data in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, movie

Is it possible to create a movie file from imported table of data?
I have an imported data in matrix form, from which I can create a ListPlot picture, choosing from imported matrix specific row that I want to see. Can I create a moving picture, showing rows from imported matrix step by step?

Answer (score 1):

This page seems a good idea to start http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/15/mathematica-qa-creating-movie-files/. The topic in Mathematicadocumentation is "Import and Export Animations" and "Data Loading and Computation" in the Reference. Both books Applied Mathematica: Getting Started, Getting It Done by W. Shaw and Mathematica in Action by Stan Wagon show examples visible on the net to reproduce and customize.

Comment: This information doesn't help me to make an animation with MY imported data. They explain, how to make an animation as a function of smth...

Comment: I found an answer hear - http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159/using-listpointplot3d-to-simulate-2d-plots-moving-in-time !!! (=